# Dynamic allocation arrays, hexa system

Tags: c++

I have problem with my code. I dont know, why it counts wrong.
This function should add two numbers on hexa system. I keep numbers on dynamic allocation arrays.

```
CHexNumber CHexNumber::cAdd(CHexNumber *pcOther) {
int i_result_len = 0;
CHexNumber c_result(i_result_len);
int i_result = 0;
int i_memory = 0;

i_result_len = (i_len > pcOther -> i_len ? i_len + 1 : pcOther -> i_len + 1);
c_result.vSetLength(i_result_len);

for (int i = 0; i < c_result.i_len; i++)
{
    i_result = pi_number[i] + pcOther->pi_number[i] + i_memory;

    if (i_memory > 0)
        i_memory--;

    if (i_result >= 16)
    {
        i_result %= 16;
        i_memory++;
    }

    c_result.pi_number[i] = i_result;
}

return(c_result); }
```

I add screen with in and out.
http://screenshooter.net/102563004/tumxpyx

Comment: Please include constructor

Comment: When you used the debugger, and single stepped through your code, which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values for the variables in that statement?

Comment: [edit] CHexNumber::CHexNumber(int iLen)
{
 iLen = DEFAULT_LEN;
 vSetNumber(iLen);
 vSetLength(iLen);
}

Comment: I mean in the post, edit it and add constructor and all helpers. IMO it looks like you are not correctly set c_result length but I can't tell until I see full code

Comment: it's .h http://pastebin.com/WSHWUnJm and .cpp http://pastebin.com/NYztg6dk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mateusz, in the constructor, you are ignoring passed argument and alway setting `DEFAULT_LEN` as a expression length, if you change this

```
CHexNumber::CHexNumber(int iLen)
{
    iLen = DEFAULT_LEN;
    vSetNumber(iLen);
    vSetLength(iLen);
}
```

to this

```
CHexNumber::CHexNumber(int iLen)
{
    vSetNumber(iLen);
    vSetLength(iLen);
}
```

---

another thing is to change this:

```
CHexNumber c_b(s_temp.length());
c_a.vSetSign(bCheckNumber(s_temp));
c_a.vChargeArray(s_temp);
c_a.getValue();
```

into this

```
CHexNumber c_b(s_temp.length());
c_b.vSetSign(bCheckNumber(s_temp));
c_b.vChargeArray(s_temp);
c_b.getValue();
```

---

and also this:

```
i_result_len = (i_len > pcOther -> i_len ? i_len + 1 : pcOther -> i_len + 1);
c_result.vSetLength(i_result_len);
```

into this:

```
i_result_len = (i_len > pcOther -> i_len ? i_len + 1 : pcOther -> i_len + 1);
c_result.vSetLength(i_result_len);
c_result.vSetNumber(i_result_len);
```

---

You also have other problems like leaking memory, and magic numbers, but lets leave it for now.

Comment: it doesn't work :( but i used the debugger as said Thomas and i found, that pcOther->pi_number[i] takes value -842150450. What can be wrong with this?

Comment: It sort of work, aside from that you are always assuming that there is always a carry. Eg 1+2 you are assuming that the result has 2 digits always, which is not true.

Comment: Uff.. that's a lot of bugs ;) check for edits

Comment: Thanks Bartosz, I found mistake. It was bad declaration on main, simple mistake.